# Power BI Measure Changed by Filter

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, measure

In Power BI I want to have a graph that shows the Average Age for any row where Open >= 60 when Type = A and Open >= 70 when Type = B. I have a slicer on the tab to choose between A or B and you can select to have both. I'd like this measure to work for this.

So that when the user clicks A in the slicer the graph will just show the Average Age for A where Open >= 60, but when neither is selected it will show for both Type A and Type B but for the different Open amounts.

Is this possible?

Example of the data:

```
Unique Id   Type    Open
101         A        50
102         A        75
103         B        80
104         B        43
105         A        80
106         B        72
107         A        22
108         B        56
109         B        66
110         A        65
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. If you supply some data or sample .pbix, we can help further.

Comment: @DavideBacci I've added some example data.